# Understanding console error "TypeError: undefined is not an object" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, feature-detection

I have a jQuery script that gives this console error in Safari 10:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iOSversion()')
```

and this in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This is the script in question (simplified):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //detect iOS version
    function iOSversion() {
        if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
            // supports iOS 2.0 and later
            var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
            return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
        }
    }

    // this causes a console error
    var ver = iOSversion();
    if (ver[0] < 10) {
        alert('this is version 9 or below');
    }

    if (ver[0] >= 10) {
        alert('this is version 10 or above');
    }

});
```

**Question:** I'm a relative beginner with JavaScript and struggling to understand what the cause of the problem is (as the variable appears to be correctly defined?) and I have no idea about the [0] error!). Can somebody help me understand what's going wrong and how to fix?

(The page this is happening on is [here](http://tenfold.webflow.io/))

Comment: Question: What does your `iOSversion` function return if the if condition is not true …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will return something only on an iOS platforms, so if you test on Chrome or Safari (macOS) you will get an error. `ver` is `undefined` and thus doesn't have a `[0]` key.

A quick fix would be to make the function return something valid on all platforms. Something like:

```
function iOSversion() {
    if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
        // supports iOS 2.0 and later
        var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
        return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
    }
    return [0]; // Return '0' by default
}
```

Maybe a better solution (depending on your exact problem) would be to not do OS detection, but rather [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection).

Comment: Hi @this.lau_ thanks for the suggestion and helpful explanation of whats happening – I've given it a try but like the other solution suggested below, using this causes the first IF statement to fire on MacOS (ie. not iOS - but I would expect the "this is not iOS" alert to fire?), I stuck it in a pen here: http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/MpJyyg

(BTW, I need to detect iOS rather than use feature detection to deal wth some quirks to do with attributes for autoplaying inline videos on iOS9)

Comment: @matt_50, your first `if` condition should be `if (ver[0] > 0 && ver[0] < 10) {`

Comment: that works thanks! While testing, I tried adding `return false` which seemed to prevent the console errors from occurring – is there anything wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 1):

your iOSVersion() function has no default case. It needs a return value in the event that the condition does not evaluate to true.

```
//detect iOS version
    function iOSversion() {
        if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
            // supports iOS 2.0 and later
            var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
            return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
        }
        else{
             return [-1];
        }
    }

    var ver = iOSversion();
    if (ver[0] < 10 && ver[0] != -1) {
        alert('this is version 9 or below');
    }
    else if (ver[0] >= 10) {
        alert('this is version 10 or above');
    }
    else{
        alert('this is not iOS');
    }
```

What happens when you try the above?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion - I tried this but it causes the first IF statement to fire on MacOS? (ie. not iOS - am I missing something?)

http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/qrRZdq

Comment: I made a mistake, please try again. ver[0] was evaluating to -1, which passes the check of <10. I added a check that it is also not equal to -1 so it should work now.

Comment: That works now thanks! (I updated the original codepen) It looks like a similar fix that @this.lau_ suggested in the post above. I appreciate your explanation of why the first IF statement was not working. As I said in the comment above, while testing I tried adding `return false` (instead of `[0]` or `[-1]`) and the console errors stopped – I did a new pen showing this here: http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/PpWpgE). If you wouldn't mind helping me understand – is there anything wrong with that approach?

Comment: I would advise against having a function return two different types - in this case being able to return an array or a boolean. It's better to keep to a single type so that you can always guarantee the type the function will return.

Comment: thanks @Our_Benefactors – very helpful!